# Meteor Galaxy deployment websocket connection fails with 301

Tags: meteor, websocket, meteor-galaxy

When connecting to `ws://my-app.com/websocket`, it fails with a `301` error (moved permanently).

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by having the force ssl enabled.

You can use CloudFlare's page rules to redirect your non-https traffic to https and disable the Galaxy option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wss://` instead of `ws://`.